# what will be laravel query to sort article with maximum like

Tags: php, laravel

> table:-
>
> > 1.articles
> >     column:= id, title, description
> >
> > 2.article_likes
> >     column:= id, user_id, article_id

- ArticleController.php

```php
public function index (Request $request)
{

        $articles = Article::join('article_likes', 'articles.id', '=','article_likes.article_id');

        if ($request->sort == "newest") {
            $articles->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
        } 
        if ($request->sort == "popular") {
            ??

        } 
        $articles = $articles->get();
        dd($articles);
}
```

Comment: You want to fetch the article with the highest number of likes?

Comment: in which you column you counting likes or no of enteries in article_likes = likes?

Comment: yes @codervine
i want to fetch the article with the highest number of likes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $articles = Article::with('articleLike');

    if ($request->sort == "newest") {
        $articles->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    } 
    if ($request->sort == "popular") {

        $articles->withCount('articleLike')
                    ->orderBy('article_like_count', 'desc');


    } 
    $articles = $articles->get();

    return $this->sendResponse("Article Sorted", $articles);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index (Request $request) {

  $articles = Article::join('article_likes', 'articles.id', '=','article_likes.article_id');

    if ($request->sort == "newest") {
        $articles->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    } 
    if ($request->sort == "popular") {
        $articles->max('like_column_name')

    } 
    $articles = $articles->get();
    dd($articles);

}
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: i can use any column name of article_likes table in place of like_column_name?

Comment: yes the column that has the number of likes in your database,

Comment: i think i am confused . i just clear you that there is no any perticular column in article_likes which store number of like

Comment: i used user_id in place of like_column_name but its not return answer which i want @codervine

Comment: Please do a `dd($your_query)` so I can see what it returns